# Dual run capacitor confusion

Tags: capacitor

I’m testing a 5/30 uF dual run capacitor off an RV AC unit that keeps tripping it’s breaker.
Readings are within spec between common and fan/herm terminals.
Also reads 4.2 uF between fan and herm terminals.
Is this to be expected, or does it indicate a problem?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Tested the only known good dual run cap within 40 miles. 4.3 uF between fan and herm. 
I expected simple continuity. 
Electricity is White magic to us simple folk.

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be measuring the two capacitors in series. The spec value would be 150/35 = 4.3 uF